# How can I convert 1930s dollars to today's (cost of living adjustment)?

Tags: webapp-rec

Google Calculator can convert one currency to another at today's exchange rates, but often I'll want to convert one currency to itself at a different time.

For example, what would $1,000 in 1930 be worth in today's dollars?

Is there a Web app to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Slap it into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) (although I still dislike the guess-the-syntax game)

Here is what you can use.

compute the current value of a historical quantity of money

`$1000 (1930 dollars)`

compute historical equivalent value of today's money

`1000 current dollars in 1930`

convert one historical quantity of money to another

`$1000 1930 dollars in 1975`

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+$1,000+in+1930+be+worth+today](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%241,000+in+1930+be+worth+today)

This returns

$ 12952.10(2010 US dollars)

Also gives the purchasing power.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://phwd.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/wapurchasepower.png))</sub>

Comment: I wish the graph was logarithmic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried to guess a syntax for converting 1930s dollars to 1975 dollars, but it was an exercise in frustration.

Comment: @Joe White As I said, I hate the guessing game. You will want `$ 1000 (1930 US dollars) in 1975` that returns this [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=$1000+1930+dollars+in+1975](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=$1000+1930+dollars+in+1975) , for a sort of guide ... type in [inflation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inflation).

Answer (score 2):

Try this site, it gives the purchasing power of money for the US and UK going back to 1257
http://eh.net/hmit/

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply an inflation based coefficient, there's an entire site on this topic: http://inflationdata.com/Inflation/Inflation/Inflation.asp.

However it is not that simple, as the raw convertion is not an indication of the real value of money. So you have to take in account purchasing power: http://www.measuringworth.com/ppowerus/